# Magento 2 API for Add a Group product to a cart

Tags: magento2.2

I need API to add a Group Product to a cart.
I have checked documentation for this on the link below:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items.html
There is nothing is mentioned for how to add a Group Product to a cart.
I have not found anything relevant to this.

Please suggest me on this if you have any idea of it.

Thanks